# How come certain words have totally different meanings?

Tags: ambiguity

I am wondering why certain words can have totally different meanings.

For example the word “crick“. On the one hand, it describes a really small river and on the other hand, it describes a muscle cramp. There is not even a remote connection between the two meanings.

Why is that so? Have words like that randomly be given those meanings/developed those meanings or is it because nobody could think of a new word, so they put different meanings on some already existing words in order for the meaning to not get confused in context (as it is two totally different ones)?

Comment: Did you mean *creek* for the "really small river"?

Comment: Yes, but it can also be “crick“, which has the same meaning.

Comment: It's most probable that there are two words: the *crick* in your neck; and a different  word, *crick*, which is an alternative spelling of *creek*. Historically the two *cricks* are most probably not related to each other, as far as etymology, per the *Oxford English Dictionary*.

Comment: How  is "light"  "not dark" and "not heavy"?

Comment: _Crick_ is a local variant for _creek_; when both are in use in a speech community, _crick_ refers to the smaller or more seasonal stream.

Comment: The word *bow* is the worst I know in this respect, with two distinct pronunciations and (at least) four completely different meanings!

Comment: @Ronald Sole: Do you know how all those meanings established? Would be interesting to know.

Comment: @HarmlessPsycho Sorry, I don't. You'll need to address the question to one of our etymologists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Crick" to mean a really small river is a regional pronunciation of "creek". 
"Crick" to describe a muscle cramp is onomatopoeia -- it describes the sound of a joint adjusting which might cause the muscle to relax.

Regional dialects and words that sound like things are two reasons words with different meanings come into being.

Another way this happens is when root words come from different languages but sound alike. "Pan" is often related to bread in languages that come from Latin -- "pan dulce" (sweet bread), "panadaria" (bread store), "pain perdu" ("lost" bread, or French toast), "empanadas" (filled bread) -- but in Greek the same word means "all" so "panamerican" comes from that origin.

Comment: And *crick* is also a regional spelling of *creek*.

Comment: Both words, in all senses, are also examples of the [phonosemantic `kr-` assonance](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/kr.pdf) in English.